# McAfee always found Virus when I use pyinstaller3 to pack my Python script

Tags: python, pyqt, pyinstaller, pyqt5, mcafee

[*** screen shortcut photo ***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cO2Su.png)

when i use pyinstaller3 to pack my python script(with PYQT5), McAfee  always alert me the runw.exe file found virus and then delete this bootloader file .

the pyinstaller is download from official website , i have no idea why this happen , and also i try this with my workmates computer , same thing happen .

so could you pls help me to settle this problem ?

thank you very much .

Comment: Generally this could be that the package is indeed infected. But it may also be a false alarm. Perhaps you should report this to the site from where you downloaded it and see what they have to say. I know there have been cases where the Windows binaries were infected (but not for python as far as I know).

Comment: Your error message mentions a virus called *artemis* and here's a link with some info about it: http://support.kaspersky.com/us/10851

Comment: @itsols This is not an "Artemis" virus but the McAfee Artemis system detecting the file (see here: https://service.mcafee.com/webcenter/portal/cp/home/articleview?locale=en-US&articleId=TS100414). Since the file came from the official site, this could be a false positive. OP, you can upload the detected file to https://www.virustotal.com/ and see what other AV vendors say.

Comment: thank you all of you , but i still not settle this problem ,now i have to changed to use console method , also i have upload the problem file to virus total.com , hope can got a good news ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Program made with PyInstaller now seen as a Trojan Horse by AVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43777106/program-made-with-pyinstaller-now-seen-as-a-trojan-horse-by-avg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend reinstalling pyinstaller3 and preventing McAfee from deleting the bootloader file.  I'd go as far as to switch antivirus software if this isn't possible.

Comment: thank you , i have re-install pyinstaller ,but McAfee still alert me the virus ... i  cannot prevent McAfee to delete the boot loader as i have no authorize todo that  ...

Answer (score 1):

Realizing this is an old thread...

if you have access to the ePO console, you can set a policy to skip scanning pyinstaller.  That will prevent this from becoming flagged as a virus.

Answer (score 0):

Actually MBAM (Malwarebytes Anti-Malware), McAfee, Avast antivirus detects the pyinstaller file as dangerous it has happened to me with both MBAM (Malwarebytes Anti-Malware) and McAfee anttivirus detects it as dangerous!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem before. It occurs when you convert your files (like images and icons) into a python file through Qt qrc resources feature. This encoded python file triggers a false alarm.

I solved it by using the classical files handling technique through runw.spec file.